# On fresh install of Chef-Server, can't create admin user due to 404

Tags: chef-infra

I've just installed a chef-server using the instructions from this page:

https://learn.chef.io/install-and-manage-your-own-chef-server/linux/install-chef-server/install-chef-server-using-your-hardware/

When I get to the step where I creating an [admin user](https://learn.chef.io/install-and-manage-your-own-chef-server/linux/install-chef-server/install-chef-server-using-your-hardware/#step6), I  get this response:

```
[root@hostname ~]# chef-server-ctl user-create administrator admin admin email@company.com PASSWORD --filename admin.pem
ERROR: The object you are looking for could not be found
Response:




<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html>
        <head>
                <title>404 Page Not Found</title>
                <style type="text/css">
html {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica;
}

body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
}

.content {
        padding: 0px 10px 10px 10px;
}

h1 {
        font-size: 14pt;
}

p {
        font-size: 10pt;
}
</style>

        </head>

        <body>
                <div class="content">
                        <h1>
                                404 Page Not Found
                        </h1>
                        <p>The requested URL was not found on this server. </p>
                        <p>Requested URL: /users/</p>
                </div>
        </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas on where to look? This is Centos 6.8

Thanks!

Comment: Is there already a web server running on that machine?

Comment: What's the output of [`chef-server-ctl status`](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_server.html#status)?

Comment: Hi! No, this host doesn't have a web server running. I have changed the ports in any event. This is the output:

Comment: Too many characters, but the output is all "run" status

Comment: Led me on the right track, I checked the tail of the logs and looks like I was clunking against a service on 8000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue, someone else was running a service on port 8000, which is what the erlang bits use in chef-server. I've added this in my chef-server.rb and the problem is solved

```
opscode_erchef['port'] = 8008
```

Reference: https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_server_optional_settings.html